# Minimum Cost Max Flow with Negative Weight Cycles?

Tags: algorithms, optimization, network-flow, max-flow

Does there exist an algorithm that can solve the minimum cost maximum flow problem even if the residual graph contains negative weight cycles?

I have an implementation that uses shortest paths to compute the minimum cost maximum flow but this fails to find the minimum cost flow even though such a flow is well defined. This is because it uses Djikstra's to find augmenting paths and gets stuck in negative weight cycles.

I found the cycle cancelling algorithm but it seems that it will augment the flow in the graph in degenerate ways i.e. it might try to circulate flow in a cycle of negative cost even though no flow was passing through those arcs in the cycle.

Comment: "This is because it uses Djikstra" -- sooo, don't use Dijkstra? Bellman-Ford deals with negative weights (!) perfectly and detects negative cycles.

Comment: Yes but Bellman Ford will just stop when it detects a negative weight cycle. Even thought shortest paths in a graph are not defined, a min cost flow is always well defined in a capcitated (finite capacity) residual network

Comment: Isn't having that cycle in hand enough to proceed?